# transitionToRoute reloading the model

Tags: ember.js

How can I transition to a route and tell Ember to **reload the model for that route**?

*My use case*:
The page I am on is for an `appointment`. After I `cancel` the appointment I need to transition to the `/schedule` route showing all the appointments except for the one I just canceled.

When I use `transitionToRoute` the canceled appoitment is still in the list. I then have to reload the browser page to see the new list.

Comment: Why don't you just remove the cancelled appointment from the collection?  It's likely cheaper than reloading the entire collection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I totally agree with @Kingpin2k's suggestion in the comments of **removing** the appointment. If for whatever reason that doesn't work for you - just transition to the route **without** supplying any model (omit the 2nd parameter) or supply an id by which the model can be looked up, which is an integer or a string. The `model` hook of the `Route` will then be invoked.

From the [docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#method_transitionToRoute):

> If a literal is passed (such as a number or a string), it will be treated as an identifier instead. In this case, the model hook of the route will be triggered

Comment: If you're supplying a string, do you have to set the serialize hook? I'm following the guide's syntax, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

if you are passing the model in transitionToRoute

in the  model route you are transitioning to simply reload the model using the setup controller hook

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
    model.reload();
    controller.set('model', model);
},
```

`model.reload()` is how you can refresh a model anytime in your application.